# How to track AMP data on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics (GA) has started showing analytics data wrt to canonical URLs now. Earlier finding AMP pages data in GA was easy as one can easily filter URLs ending with "/amp". But now finding AMP data in GA doesn't seem easy.

The 'Source' dimension of AMP pages is like 'example-com.cdn.ampproject.org' so that can be used to filter AMP data (i.e. GA > Acquisition > Referrals > 'Source' dimension OR Behaviour > Site Content > Landing Pages > Primary or Secondary dimension as 'example-com.cdn.ampproject.org') but for me, this data is not consistent with AMP data that I am getting from Google Search Console.

[Custom Dimensions can be used to identify AMP sessions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9264222) but is there any other way to precisely track AMP data without using the custom dimension? Thank you.